# present progressive impossible with "when"

Tags: present-continuous, progressive-aspect

Could you explain me why "is cooking" is a wrong answer

> Who **is cooking** food in your family when your Mom is away? (Incorrect)
>   Who **cooks** food in your family when your Mom is away? (Correct)

If I consider that his or her mom is almost aways at home, so it does not happen very often.
Maybe with **when** you must have short action so past simple is needed

Answer (score 3):

The time-condition in the following sentence can be understood in a couple of ways:

> Who is cooking food in your family *when your Mom is away*?

...whenever your mom is away

or

...now that your mom is not living with you, or is not at home with you, i.e. when = "given that"

Since "is cooking" requires an *ongoing, continuous* scenario, we cannot say:

**Who *is cooking* food in your family whenever you mom is away?**   (not OK)

because *whenever* expresses a *sporadic or intermittent* temporal condition. The simple present can be used to express habitual or customary action.

**Who *does* the cooking in your family whenever your mom is away?**  (OK)

**Who *cooks* in your family whenever your mom is away?** (OK)

Answer:  I do. |  My sister does |  My dad does.

But if we understand the "when" clause to mean "now that your mom is not living with the family or now that your mom is not at home with you", we *can* ask:

**Who *is doing* the cooking in your family now that your mom is not living with you?**    (OK)
**Who *is doing* the cooking in your family now that your mom is not at home with you?** (OK)

**Who *is cooking* in your family now that your mom is not living with you?**  (OK)
**Who *is cooking* in your family now that your mom is not at home with you?**  (OK)

because in that case, the condition is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the simple present in your exercise has nothing to do with the presence of **when**.

[Here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html), as you can see we use simple present:

> to express the idea that an action is repeated or usual. The action can be a habit, a hobby, a daily event, a scheduled event or something that often happens.